# THT components reliability and advantages for small scale production

Tags: components, repair, reliability, production

Examining this question in the "manufacturing of not consumer electronics".

I'm looking for an opinion by others about some statements that I take for correct.

1. Are THT components in general more reliable than SMT when used in boards that are subject to mechanical shock? (Like vibration and twisting of the PCB.)
2. Are the THT component boards more repair friendly than SMT?
3. In the production of little number of boards (<10) are the SMT the right choice or the little number of boards does not make the SMT give advantages over THT?

Comment: For 2 and 3 I think this really depends on your situation.  Either could be easier or cheaper, but if you aren't familiar with SMD parts you might not be comfortable repairing them.

Comment: also note that this really depends on your idea of reliability. Both in aerospace and in automotive, you'll mostly find SMD, but with additional precautions. Personally, I had not **once** to replace a SMD component due to mechanical stress. This feels like a question of what you use this for, in which environment. "Virbration and twisting" really isn't specific enough.

Comment: @gino:  I use SMD parts almost exclusively in my hobby projects.  With careful design (choice of components,) I can make my PCBS so that I can assemble them with nothing more than a standard soldering iron.  Given a choice, I would rather use SMD than THT.

Comment: I have had SMD capacitors die from stress (cracking due to mechanical stress.)  I've also had (large) THT break off the board.

Comment: gino you vaguely mention "artisanal boards". Now, it really gets unclear. Tell us what environment you need to work with, and define "reliability"; your understanding of what "reliable" means might simply so far off from what we mean with that term that we're not speaking the same language.

Comment: 1. Depends. In general I would say no due to more mass. 2. If you design for repair you are going to need to repair it. Design for manufacturing instead. 3. My last run was for 10 boards at my local EMS. All SMD. Took a few minutes to pick-and-place them. Bake. Done.

Answer (score 2):

1. Perhaps, but keep in mind that SMT has been used in manned space applications since at least Apollo, so it's really down to the quality of the design whether it meets your particular requirements. Lighter SMT parts have advantages.
2. Generally, though that has as much to do with the relative crudeness of THT parts compared to SMT. For example, a 144-pin or 208-pin THT part (if it existed) would likely be very difficult to remove from a board without damaging the board. A BGA or TQFP is not so bad with the proper tools.
3. With a few relatively inexpensive tools, small scale production of SMT boards is not a problem. You're more likely to run into critical parts that are simply not available in THT or are prohibitively large or expensive. Even jellybean parts such as logic-level MOSFETs are like that, let alone ASICs. Newer (as in the last 20 years or so ) parts are very often simply not introduced in THT packages. Saving PCB real estate might be a cost issue in large quantities, but even in small quantities you might need to make the device small for other reasons.

Comment: re: 3. It's also worth noting that things that are rated for higher reliability are these days quasi non-existing in anything but SMD.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. but many surface mount components also have leads.
2. Depends. Removing the component is easier with thru-hole since you
   can snip it out (which can also be done for surface mount components
   with leads). But cleaning up the thru-hole can be a major
   pain-in-ther-ass. It is also inconvenient to fasten it in place so
   you can solder it upside down. It is also inconvenient to need to
   bend the new leads to match but once you do you don't have to be as
   precise in placing the component on the board as with surface mount.

   Components where multiple leads are under the component are a pain
   though since you can't snip and you run into the same issue as
   surface mount below where you have to heat all the pins at the same
   time, but unlike surface mount there is often no equipment to help
   you short of having a soldering iron and hand for each pin (see
   below).

   Surface mount is smaller and so positioning needs to be more precise
   and bridging is easier if you do not know what you're doing. But no
   need to flip the board over, bend leads, or clean out thru-holes.
   Removing some surface mount components can be challenging or impossible without
   the right equipment since pins must be heated up at the same time if
   you cannot snip pins (hot tweezers, or hot air, or special iron tips
   that hit the entire IC, or blade tips that hit a row of pins
   combined with picks to lift that row).

   Also, surface mount components with hidden pads underneath is a
   different challenge altogether. You need hot air for that.
3. Surface mount is easier for mass production but that doesn't mean it's any more difficult for small scale production.

Comment: yes maybe I wasn't so clear (my fault) my question is related to  "field repair" and to "small scale artisanal production"

Comment: @gino I am not familiar with field repair conditions or equipment setup and availability.